# How to set the international target of a multi-language site in Google Search Console

Tags: seo

How to set the international target of a multi-language site in Google Search Console?

```
My site is like this: 
US & CA: www.mydomain.com/en,
UK: www.mydomain.com/en,
FR: www.mydomain.com/fr, 
DE: www.mydomain.com/de, 
China: www.mydomain.com/cn,
..........
```

How to set it in Google Search Console(Webmaster Tool)
It only allow me to check one. How to process it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is insignificant factor for Google ranking, there are dosens of factors that should be considered first.

If your domain is gTLD or ngTLD and you want to leave your website as is, you can simply unset the targeting and Google will do the rest for you.

Google guideline is here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en

Even though using subdomains is not without its drawbacks, I would suggest using them this way:

For us/uk/ca (do not set targeting in search console): en.yourdomain.com
For France: fr.yourdomain.com
etc.

You can set targeting of a specific subdomain to a specific country only if you want people of that country (and not people from other countries with same language) visit your website. For instance, setting targeting of fr.yourdomain.com to France will boost your ranking slightly for residents of France and not for the residents of other French-speaking (African) countries.

Also mind that setting a target does not give you a significant boost in a specific country and does not cut off the visitors from other countries altogether.

Comment: it is a long answer. The gTLD is my domain, and it is a good tip or leak. I searched more on Google for gTLD, and find some answers, and then I decided the unlisted selection. Thank you very much. You helped me.